# How to jump into the needed lines in a document using nano?

Tags: 12.04, nano

I want to jump through lines faster in ubuntu 12.04 server.
For example my errorlog shows me an error in line 514, how can I jump to the line directly using nano or pico ? If it's not possible, how to make it possible.
I prefer to stay without any other tools if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within nano, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (that is, hold down ctrl and press underscore), and then you will be prompted to enter a line.

If you want to open the file focused on a specific line, you can use from the command line:

```
nano +514 file.txt
```